# how users can get data from my server as a bridge to facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, proxy

Please view this sample facebook share code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The code acts in clinet area (It runs on user's browser).

In some countries facebook is filtered and you can not access it without an unti-filter...

Is there a way to call `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0` via server? not via user? I hope you underestand me. I want my server act as unti-filter...and user get data from my server as a bridge to facebook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even if it was that script will do other request to Facebooks servers to get information. If Facebook is blocked it will not work